# C# .Net Properties (GET, SET) returns blank when i add text

Tags: c#, .net, get, set

Hi all this is my second day when i get stuck after hours and hours of google.
I have one form and one class were the heavy code is, in the form i have some check boxes and textboxes, when the class program runs based of the checkboxex the code will run only part of code.
But if i try to return a checkbox it only return false or if i try to textbox it only return blank eaven if i tick the textbox or if i add text to the textbox.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lading");
        this.textBox1.Text = "THIS IS TXT.1";
        this.textBox2.Text = "THIS IS TXT.2";
        this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
        this.checkBox2.Checked = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Work_.Work wrk = new Work_.Work();
        wrk.Testing();
    }

    private string result1;
    public string test1
    {
        get { return result1 = this.textBox1.Text; }
        set { }
    }

    private string result2;
    public string test2
    {
        get { return result2 = this.checkBox1.Checked.ToString(); }
        set { }
    }

    }
}
```

and the class file (it is added in to a "Work" folder)

```
namespace WinFormsApp1.Work_
{
    class Work
    {
    public void Testing()
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();

        string Return = form.test1;
        MessageBox.Show(Return);

        string Return2 = form.test2;
        MessageBox.Show(Return2);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Form1_Load` does not execute just because you have created an instance of the class. It will execute when it shows.

Comment: @GSerg : Ok, but i was expecting if i manually change the text in the form i will get a velue, i use `Form1_Load` jut not to have an empty form.

Comment: Your going to have to `Application.Run` or `Form.Show` it for the load

Comment: If you change the text manually after the form has shown, then yes, you will read the value back via `test1`. But you have not written code that would read this value from `test1` after the form has shown.

Comment: You need to explain “what” this code is trying to accomplish. The `Work_` class makes no sense. It has no properties and only contains a method that displays 2 message boxes with the values from the text boxes on `Form1`? This is strange in a sense that the `Work_` class is “created” in `Form1s` `button_Click` event? Inside the button click event the code already has access to the text boxes… why create a `Work_` object to do something it can do itself. In other words, put the two message box lines from the work class into the button click event. There is no need for the `Work_` class.

Comment: @JohnG this was only a test for me, because my code is quite complex, what i want to do is to loop thru the code and if i have 10 checkboxes, each time will check one chekbox and if it is false to skip using goto statement.

Comment: @GSerg i was using load to fill the form automatically, but with below answer it works using load. But is curios i get blank value because the Forsm1 was loaded.

Comment: If your current… _” code is quite complex”_ …. I do not see how “adding” complexity is going to help. But go for it, obviously there is more going on that what you have provided.

Comment: @JohnG this will reduce the coplexity, because i will not copy paste the code 10 times i will loop thru the same code 10 times and check the checkboxes. About the complexity it is ... because i create read registry, hash some values to keep things private , and some other features. i decided to create a small example code for my ease and for yours. i am not using comments in my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `Work` class you are creating a new `Form` and therefore accessing it will not give you the values from your original form. One way to do this is to pass the form to your `Work` class like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Work_.Work wrk = new Work_.Work();
    wrk.Testing(this);
}
```

And in the `Work` class:

```
public void Testing(Form1 form)
{

    string Return = form.test1;
    MessageBox.Show(Return);

    string Return2 = form.test2;
    MessageBox.Show(Return2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This was the answer. Kind regards

Comment: If this answer helped you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it

Answer (score 0):

This definition of a property is probably not what you want:

```cs
private string result1;
    public string test1
    {
        get { return result1 = this.textBox1.Text; }
        set { }
    }
```

This updates the variable `result1` with the contents of the textBox and return it. You do not need the variable at all here. Just simplify the property to

```cs
public string test1
    {
        get { this.textBox1.Text; }
    }
```

Your actual problem however is that the `Form1_Load` method never executes if you don't show the dialog. Insert `form.ShowDialog()` after `Form1 form = new Form1();`.